# end point to accept multiple values, including query strings

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view which should accept an end point with a query parameter, as well as without a parameter.

```
http://localhost:8001/v1/subjects?owner_ids=62,144
```

and

```
http://localhost:8001/v1/subjects
```

Here's my view file...

```
class SubjectPagination(JsonApiPageNumberPagination):
    """
    Required for frontend to retrieve full list.
    """
    max_page_size = 5000


class SubjectViewSet(Subject.get_viewset()):
    pagination_class = SubjectPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        queryset = Subject.objects.all()

        if self.request.GET['owner_ids']:
            owner_id_list = self.request.GET['owner_ids'].split(',')
            owner_id_list_integer = []

            for i in owner_id_list:
                owner_id_list_integer.append(int(i))

            return queryset.filter(organization__in=owner_id_list_integer)

        else:

            return queryset


SubjectUserRoleViewSet = Subject.get_by_user_role_viewset(
    SubjectViewSet, GroupRoleMap, Role)
```

I am trying to figure out how to handle both the end points? Please advice what needs to be done at the view to handle a URI with or without query strings?

Here's the urls.py

```
router.register(r'subjects', views.SubjectViewSet)
```

Comment: by default, Django will handle both cases.

Comment: You're just asking for other to make your own work. The question is not specific enough to be answered here.

Comment: @Linovia Apologies if you felt that way. I am a newbie to django and trying to understand how to do stuff which is not so obviously documented. Hence the questions.

Comment: @JPG - then there is something missing in my urls.py or view file, right now the view is called only if there is a query param present.

Comment: @AverageJoe unfortunately the question doesn't say what you really want to do. As I said, it's too opened. Please have a look at FAQ about how to ask questions so we can provide meaningful answers and help you

Comment: @Linovia The objective is to return both the end points, one with query string, and another without to serve from the same view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is a good practice to send the parameters in url-form-encode, avoiding things like that, in this case for send a list you could send id as:

```
?owner_ids[]=62&owner_ids[]=144
```

the querydict its going to be like this :

```
<QueryDict: {'owner_ids[]': ['62', '144']}>
```

and you could process it easily, like this

```
self.request.GET.getlist('owner_ids[]', [])
```

remember to use the get and get list functions of the request method GET and POST, to avoid dict errors.

Second, split returns a list the for statement in owner list id is totally unnecessary, and the queryset statement __in accept array of strings, if you actually want to convert all the items to integers use list comprehensions. For example, to convert all the items in a list to integer, just have to use:

```
owner_ids = [int(i) for i in owner_ids ]
```

this is way more fast in python and way more pythonic, and also cool too see.

and last, all urls should finish in /, even django has a settings for that [called append_slash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash)

this is what i can tell about the ambiguous question you are asking, in the next times please write questions more precisely that help people help you.

Comment: Thank you. Will the above in a view satisfy both the end points /subjects as well a /subjects?owner_ids[]=62&owner_ids[]=144  --- this has been my challenge.

Comment: the solution helps you in every view that has the GET and POST data in the request, this helps you with DRF, custom views or generic class views, is the same solution for everything.

Comment: Thank you. If that's the case, what changes I may require in urls.py file to capture an optional parameter like ?owner_ids=1,2" etc. The view is not accepting the /subjects/ call, it only accepts a call with the query param, hence the question

Comment: router.register(r'subjects', views.SubjectViewSet) # urls.py entry. View is in the original question, it has a get_queryset() method.

Comment: what error appear, as i see there should not be any problem

Comment: There is no error, but when I call the end point without the query string and with the query string the results are the same. Basically it does not go inside the get_queryset() method.

Comment: could you please print the self.request.GET, and update your post with the result?